# i have two local repos, one at school one at home, and the remote repo on github, how do i get commits from one local repo to sync to the other local

Tags: git, github, repository, local

as stated in the title i have two local repos on two different machines and one github repo synced with both of them remotely, how do i make it so that when i make a change in local repo 1, commit stage and push it to the remote repo, that those changes will update local repo 2 without having to completely remove and reconfig it on the pc. this is probably a noob question but im a noob to github and when i looked into it i tried most of the different commands etc but almost every time i tried any of them i just got the error message 'fatal: not a gir repository (or any of the parent directories): .git.

Comment: Are you familiar with `git pull`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the reason, why there is Git. *Local* repositories (copies) on different computers (at all team-members, or in your case: home and school) and ONE *remote* repository. In your situation there is no team who works together on one repository, there are only two station (same user), where you have clone the same repository. But you must handle this as you work in a team.

Now if you made changes, you will commit this changes and push it to remote. That the other members who works with on this repository (or your other local station (home-school)) become the changes from remote to local, they must pull this changes, that the local repository is up-to-date with the remote. And that you can do with `git pull`.

I advise you to do a *[git tutorial](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial)*, so that you can handle the most common git commands.